# Not getting proper html page view and a browser error

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I created a home page named `index.html` . In this page I wrote some `navbar` code. One of the option is login. When anyone click that, it will redirect to `login.html`. login page is redirecting fine but showing some error in browser like:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
>   in the transfer protocol.

Here is my code:

/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>AdvisorKhoj</title>

            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
            <link href="./css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- font-awesome CSS -->
            <link href="./css/font-awesome/font-awesome.min" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Style CSS -->
            <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        </head>     
        <body>
        <header class="masthead">
                <nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" role = "navigation">

               <div class = "navbar-header">
                  <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
                     data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
                     <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>

                  <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">DemoDemo</a>
               </div>

               <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">

                  <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                        
                     <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle dropbtn" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                           Tools
                           <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>                        
                        <ul class = "dropdown-content">
                           <li><a href = "#calculator.html">Calculator</a></li>
                        </ul>                       
                     </li>                   
                    <li><a href ="login.html">Account</a></li>  
                  </ul>
               </div>

            </nav>
        </header>
        <!-- javascript plugins -->     
    <script src="javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/wow.min.js"></script>
</body>     
</html>
```

/login.html

```
        <div class="inner-container container">
    <div class="login-wrapper" >
        <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
            <p class="f-s-20 text-center"><b>please login</b></p>
                <div class="form-group m-t-40">
                    <label>Enter your E-mail ID</label>
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$email" type="text" id="email" class="form-control" />
                    <span id="EmailResult" class="error"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group pos-rel">
                    <label>Enter your Password</label>
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="f-s-13">
                    Forgot your password? <a href="ForgotPassword"><b>Click here to recover</b></a>
                    </p>


                    <span class="error" id="LoginError"></span>
                    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnlogin" value="Login" onclick="return validateLogin();" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnlogin" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
                <p class="m-t-30">Not a registered user? <a href="SignUp.html"><b>Signup now</b></a>
            </p>
        </div>                            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you declare the charset in login.html as you do in index.html?

Comment: Why doesn't login.html have a `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<html>`, `<head>`, etc.?